# Android Studio как рисовать простые фигуры?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, libgdx

Различные источники для рисования ссылаются на 
import android.graphics.Canvas; или на import android.graphics.Path;

Android Studio оба варианта не знает, таких библиотек нет
Где взять эти библиотеки? Или есть ли альтернативный вариант для рисования простых фигур?(круг, прямоугольник)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пишу проект в android studio, создавал с помощью libGDX

Comment: Может вы SDK не подключили? Эти классы из стандартного SDK берутся. А в libGDX разве не своими классами можно все это реализовать?

Comment: @pavel163 проверил в структуре проекта, путь к sdk указан правильно(D:\sdk без него проект нельзя запускать)

Comment: @pavel163 а libgdx вроде как может отрисовывать только текстуры, то есть существует SpriteBatch, в котором как я понял можно придать форму отрисовки текстуры, например в круге

Comment: Удалите этот импорт и в месте где этот класс используется вызовите ImportClass. У вас все указано корректно, возможно какой то глюк студийки

Comment: Попробуй invalidate cache and restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел вот такую альтернативу для рисования, из libgdx

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
ShapeRenderer sr= new ShapeRenderer();
sr.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
    sr.setColor(Color.RED);
    sr.rect(10,10,30,30);
    sr.end();
    sr.isDrawing();
```

Comment: Вот о чём и речь. В чистом Android Studio рисование на канве - свои способы. А если Libgdx используете, то это уже совсем другие способы. Фактически это два разных языка (не зря Libgdx называют фреймворком).